# how to get unordered key value pair

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

The problem is that ; I am retrieving a key value data object pair from database it is like

```
(select * from xyz ORDER BY letter DESC)

3 z,
2 y,
1 x
```

And Im putting these to a Long, String HashMap pair. The problem is when I putting these to Map pair, the order is changing.
It appears as

```
1 x,
2 y,
3 z
```

How can i preserve data as in first situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead! That will keep the order.

Comment: You shouldn't link to out-of-date javadocs.  The world mostly uses Java 1.6, not 1.4.2

Comment: No it is not OK.  The 1.4.2 docs are SIGNIFICANTLY out of date.  For instance, they don't show that LinkedHashMap is actually a generic class in a modern JVM.

Comment: Changed the link to Java 8 :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Answer (score 3):

use [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead of [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). the order would be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`.

> Some map implementations, like the `TreeMap` class, make specific guarantees as to their order; others, like the `HashMap` class, do not.

- from http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html